# awscloudwatchlogs exporter in opentelemetry collector

Tags: logging, open-telemetry, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights, exporter, access-keys

How do I configure my opentelemetry collector to export logs to Amazon awscloudwatchlogs?
I have created a log-group called `log-group-test-1` and under it a `log-stream-test-1`
Right now, I am using the current configuration for the exporter as shown below:

```
awscloudwatchlogs:
      region: ap-south-1
      access_key_id: <my_access_key_id> 
      secret_access_key: <my_secret_access_key>
      log_group_name: log-group-test-1
      log_stream_name: log-stream-test-1
```

But when I deploy the collector using helm, the collector pod goes into the `CrashLoopBackOff` state. And when I check the logs of the collector, this is what I get:

```
Error: failed to get config: cannot unmarshal the configuration: 1 error(s) decoding:

* error decoding 'exporters': error reading configuration for "awscloudwatchlogs": 1 error(s) decoding:

* '' has invalid keys: access_key_id, secret_access_key
2023/04/10 11:07:32 collector server run finished with error: failed to get config: cannot unmarshal the configuration: 1 error(s) decoding:

* error decoding 'exporters': error reading configuration for "awscloudwatchlogs": 1 error(s) decoding:

* '' has invalid keys: access_key_id, secret_access_key
```

Is this an AWS access key id issue or something else that I'm not considering?

I tried deleting the old access keys and creating a new one and using it, but that doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the [docs](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/exporter/awscloudwatchlogsexporter), the `awscloudwatchlogs` exporter doesn't have the `access_key_id` and `secret_access_key` fields but rather gets the AWS credentials from the [default credential chain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/configuring-sdk.html#specifying-credentials). That's the reason you see this error message. Remove these two fields from the config and provide the credentials via one of the methods such as environment variables or a shared credentials file and it should work.